# Parsing application/json data stored in a buffer to JSON

Tags: node.js, json, parsing, buffer

I am building a web monitoring system (https proxy) that monitors data of the "POST" request.

I am able to parse "text/plain" data using

let buffer = Buffer.from(value["requestData"]["data"]);
requestData = buffer.toString("utf8")

however, I am unable to parse buffer data incase of "application/json"
I have tried everything

JSON.parse(buffer),JSON.parse(buffer.toString("utf8")) but nothing is working

```
const readData = function() {
    RequestDetails.find((err, res) => { //find by mongoose model
        if (err)
            console.log(err);
        else {
            console.log(typeof(res));
            console.log(res.length);
            res.forEach((value, i) => { //loop through each object
                let requestData = null;
                let method = value["requestOptions"]["method"];
                let contentType = value["requestOptions"]["headers"]["Content-Type"];
                let buffer = Buffer.from(value["requestData"]["data"]);

                if (method === "POST") {  //if request is a post request
                    if (contentType) {
                        if (contentType.indexOf(content_types[0]) != -1) {  //if application/json is in Content-Type header 
                            console.log("IS JSON");
                            requestData = buffer.toJSON();
                        } else {
                            requestData = buffer.toString("utf8")
                        }
                    } else {
                        requestData = buffer.toString("utf8")
                    }

                    console.log("Method: " + method)
                    console.log("Content-type: " + contentType);
                    console.log("Buffer: " + requestData);
                    console.log(_.keys(requestData))

                    // console.log("Buffer: " + JSON.stringify(requestData));
                    console.log("");
                }

            });

        }

    });
}
```

```
{ requestOptions:
   { hostname: 'incoming.telemetry.mozilla.org',
     port: 443,
     path:
      '/submit/telemetry/f7498210-bc23-4a00-87d8-8cf7c6c6dfc5/health/Firefox/70.0.1/release/20191030021342?v=4',
     method: 'POST',
     headers:
      { Host: 'incoming.telemetry.mozilla.org',
        'User-Agent':
         'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0',
        Accept: '*/*',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        Date: 'Sun, 08 Dec 2019 13:49:39 GMT',
        'Content-Encoding': 'gzip',
        'Content-Length': '336',
        Connection: 'keep-alive' } },
  protocol: 'https',
  url:
   'https://incoming.telemetry.mozilla.org/submit/telemetry/f7498210-bc23-4a00-87d8-8cf7c6c6dfc5/health/Firefox/70.0.1/release/20191030021342?v=4',
  requestData:{
         type:"Buffer",
         data [...]
}
}
```

Comment: Show your code, not only the `JSON.parse` part, where is `value["requestData"]["data"]` coming from, a `ReadableStream` ?

Comment: The proxy intercepts the request(inform of an object) and saves the data in a database, the object is too long to post here

Comment: Put the rest of your code, the function where that's happening. Otherwise it's impossible to help you. Also without knowing what `value["requestData"]["data"]` is there's very little we can do.

Comment: Please take a look i have added the code and the object